# What query am I able to perform with Lambda(Method Syntax) and not with (Query Syntax)?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

What query am I able to perform with Lambda(Method Syntax) and not with (Query Syntax)?

The questions is simple, this is an example of both:

```
    int[] numbers = { 5, 10, 8, 3, 6, 12};

    //Query syntax:
    IEnumerable<int> numQuery1 = 
        from num in numbers
        where num % 2 == 0
        orderby num
        select num;

    //Method syntax:
    IEnumerable<int> numQuery2 = numbers.Where(num => num % 2 == 0).OrderBy(n => n);
```

What would be a query that I can perform Method Syntax and not in the Query Syntax?

Comment: By "linq" do you mean "query expressions"? If you use `foo.Where(x => x.Name == "Fred")` that's still using LINQ...

Comment: yes, "query expression" vs "code expression using lambda"

Comment: what? lambda is a language perk, linq is some syntax sugar + framework and the linq framework ends up being used with lambdas a lot

Comment: please... give a chance to update before closing..

Comment: do you mean extension methods like `Take` `Skip` `TakeWhile` `SkipWhile` `Distinct` `Intercept` `Except` `Any` `All` and so on , which can't be expressed using query syntax, but can using extension method syntax?

Comment: Darn it, just when I was most of the way through what I'm pretty sure would have actually been a useful ansewr...

Comment: Skeet, you rep greedy bugger.

Comment: @ThePoet - you can update after it's closed and it might be reopened.... or not.

Comment: just one vote required to reopen!

Comment: @JonSkeet you can post that answer now ;) Im interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(This is a shorter answer than I was originally writing, but other answers have already provided some of the details.)

There are two reasons one might wish to use lambda expressions instead of query expressions:

- Operations which simply aren't covered by query expressions, whether that's methods which aren't covered at all (e.g. `Count`) or overloads of operations which *are* included in query expressions, but not in that form. For example:

  ```
  var indexedValues = values.Select((value, index) => new { value, index });
  ```

  There's no query expression form which uses that overload.
- When the lambda form is simpler. For example, if you've only got a single projection or filter, it can be simpler to do it in one call than set up the fluff of a query expression:

  ```
   var adults = people.Where(person => person.Age > 18);
  ```

  Vs:

  ```
   var adults = from person in people
                where person.Age > 18
                select person;
  ```

  Additionally, the lambda expression approach is somewhat tidier when you want to continue the expression after the query. For example, creating a list of the names of adults:

  ```
   var names = people.Where(person => person.Age > 18)
                     .Select(person => person.Name)
                     .ToList();
  ```

  Vs:

  ```
   var names = (from person in people
                where person.Age > 18
                select person.Name).ToList();
  ```

  The brackets end up being a bit irritating.

Where query expressions shine is in the operations which introduce *transparent identifiers* - joins, `SelectMany`, `let` etc. While you obviously *can* translate such code into lambda form, it can end up really ugly.

Answer (score 4):

You can find complete list of methods that have corresponding keywords within query expression syntax here: [Query Expression Syntax for Standard Query Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882642.aspx). List contains information about both C# and VB.NET support. Any method that is not listed there is not available neither in C# nor VB.NET.

Interesting thing is, that there is a bit more available in VB.NET then in C#.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do a `select top 10` in query syntax. You can use `.Take(10)` in method syntax.

Aggregate functions are not supported either.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ query syntax translates directly to extension method syntax. However, the reverse is *not* true. There are way more extension methods than supported by the LINQ query syntax keywords.

So, with method syntax you can do *exactly the same or more* than with LINQ query syntax. Usually LINQ query syntax is nicer to read.

```
// LINQ query syntax
var query = 
    from num in numbers
    where num % 2 == 0
    orderby num
    select num;

// Corresponding method syntax
var query = numbers
    .Where(num => num % 2 == 0)
    .OrderBy(num => num)
    .Select(num => num);
```

A simple example of what you can do with method syntax and not with query syntax (since there are no keywords for it):

```
var query = numbers
    .First();
```

You can combine both if you want:

```
var query = 
    (from num in numbers
    where num % 2 == 0
    orderby num
    select num)
    .First();
```

Apart from `First`, there are tons of LINQ extension methods (`Sum`, `Average`, `Max`...) that have no keywords in LINQ query syntax.

---

By the way, because LINQ query syntax maps to extension methods, you are *not* restricted to using LINQ extension methods. If you define on your own custom objects a `Select` and `Where` method that both accept a delegate, then you can use LINQ query syntax *on your own objects*! How cool is that? For example, a nonsensical example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass Where(Func<string, bool> function)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public List<string> Select(Func<string, string> function)
    {
        return new List<string>();
    }
}

MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
var x = from m in myClass
        where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(m)
        select m;
```